# Download GHDL with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, ghdl

Good evening,

I wanted to download GHDL so I did this command :

> sudo apt-get install ghdl

But I have a message who said that no version of the GHDL package is disponible, but that it exists in the database.
And they said that the package GHDL doesn't have a version who can be installed.

I try this command too :

> sudo apt-get install ghdl gtkwave

But I get the same message. So, my question is : how can I download GHDL? I'm on Ubuntu, with the 16.04 version.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm really sorry, but isn't stackoverflow the place to ask this kind of question? I'm new and closing this topic won't help me. Can you explain where must I post? This is an other website?

Comment: There are many different stackexchanges. The unix stackexchange (link in my previous comment) or the ask ubuntu stack exchange would be a more appropriate location to ask about software install issues. This site (as per the FAQ is geared towards specific programming issues.

Comment: Okay, I understand, I will post there. Thank you ! (And so, how can I close this topic? )

Comment: I believe you can flag your question to be migrated. There should also be user controls to voluntary close if you look near the edit link.

Answer (score 1):

## Compile and install ghdl from github

```sh
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y git make gnat zlib1g-dev
git clone https://github.com/ghdl/ghdl
cd ghdl
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
sudo make install
```

## You may also want to install `gtkwave` so you can simulate things

```sh
sudo apt install gtkwave
```

Here is a `ghdl` [example project](https://github.com/ErezBinyamin/MAC_Unit) with a Makefile you may find useful.